# Given a sentence, return a sentence with the words reversed

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, reverse

```
def master_yoda(text):
    txt_elements=text.split()
    index=-1
    reverse=[]
    i=0
    while i <= len(txt_elements):
        reverse.append(txt_elements[index])
        index=index-1
        i+=1
    final=' '.join(reverse)
    return final
print(master_yoda('i adore that'))
```

I cannot understand why I keep on getting errors about unindentation.

Here is an example:

- *Input*: "I am beautiful"
- *Output*: "beautiful am I"

Comment: I didn't get an unindentation error, but I did get `IndexError: list index out of range` for line 7, `reverse.append(txt_elements[index])`. Please make a [mre]. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

Just change

```
while i <= len(txt_elements):
```

to

```
while i < len(txt_elements):
```

Bear in mind you could just do this instead:

```
def master_yoda(text):
    return ' '.join(text.split()[::-1])
```

In this example, `[::-1]` reverses the list using slicing. You could also use the [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) python builtin - see [comment by @wjandrea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59196910/given-a-sentence-return-a-sentence-with-the-words-reversed/59196942#comment104612320_59196942)

Answer (score 1):

If the length of `txt_elements` is 3, the maximum index is 2, since python starts indexing at 0. `i` in your while loop will eventually be 3 (`i <= len(txt_elements)`), which causes an index error due to `txt_elements[3]`. See other answers for solutions.

Answer (score 1):

*(This started as a comment but got too big. It's mostly related advice, but I put a solution at the bottom.)*

The more Pythonic way to loop over indices is

```
for i in range(len(txt_elements))
```

or if you use the items,

```
for i, item in enumerate(txt_elements)
```

But since `i` isn't used, to loop the same number of times, you could use

```
for _ in txt_elements
```

But then since you're using the loop to build another list and no other processing, you could use

```
reverse = reversed(txt_elements)
```

And at that point you might as well compress it to one line, like @CDJB recommends:

```
def master_yoda(text):
    return ' '.join(reversed(text.split()))
```

Answer (score 1):

def master_yoda(text):

```
x=text.split()

x.reverse()

return " ".join(x)
```